# Not able to start another window from main class

Tags: java, swing

Here is my class program..

```
package sample;


public class Sample {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        newda l = new newda();
        l.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Then is the next Class newda

```
package sample;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class newda extends JApplet  {

    JButton ab ;
    public void init()
    {   
        Container ac = getContentPane();
        ac.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        ab= new JButton("Show");
        ac.add(ab);
    }

}
```

When I run the newda class a window with show button is displayed (I am not able to add images of the output). When I run the project, the main class of Sample should setvisible the newda window to true and produce the same result, but nothing shows up. The project execution gets completed in 1 sec.

However this works when I use JFrame. I want to know why it doesn't work when not using JFrame.

Comment: Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 1):

Take some time to learn the difference between applets and windows

- [Using Top-Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)
- [Java Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/)
- [How to Make Frames (Main Windows)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)

An applet is a container which is meant to be embedded within a browser window, it does not have a concept of it's own window.

Change `public class newda extends JApplet {` to something more like `public class NewDa extends JFrame {`

You may also want to take a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and make sure you are creating your UI from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Answer (score 1):

```
public class newda extends JApplet  {
```

This is an applet.  An applet is not a 'window' the same as a frame, but needs a web page to be embedded in.

The reason you are thinking of an applet as a window is *probably* that your IDE shows applets inside a `JFrame`.  E.G. the applet viewer is a `JFrame` which hosts applets.